# how to link two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one sql table with two columns in which one will act has a parent and another will act has a child.

please find the below table

```
Id  name    parent
1   Chandan null
2   raju    1
3   anand   1
4   gsfsgs  null
8   gggg    2
9   ffff    2
```

Here I need to get the below out has

```
 Id  name     count
 1   Chandan    2
 2   raju       2
 3   anand      0
 4   gsfsgs     0
 8   gggg       0
 9   ffff       0
```

Here what I'm trying

```
select id, name, (select count(*) from table where parentid=id) as count
```

But I'm not getting the proper result.

Comment: What result are you getting? What result did you want to get?

Comment: You need a reference to the outer table in the sub-query.

Answer (score 5):

Do a self-join

```
SELECT t1.Id,
       t1.name,
       COUNT(t2.Id) AS count
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.Id = t2.parent
GROUP BY t1.Id,
         t1.name
```

Comment: That GROUP BY isn't valid in newer MySQL versions. (Unless in compatibility mode.)

Comment: @Matt Sorry, I initially answered this on a cell phone.  Then, when you commented, I fired up MySQL Workbench, and all is tested and working correctly now.

Answer (score 2):

The sub-query needs to be correlated, i.e. it needs a reference to the outer query:

```
select id, name, (select count(*) from table t2 where t2.parentid = t1.id) as count
from table t1
```

However, a `left join` will probably have better performance.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, wait a minute, the sub-query will return 0 when no row found.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the `SUM()` is the one having trouble. sorry.

Comment: jarlh thank you,  i'm going with your answer has its give me  proper result for my requriment

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation using a subquery AND a join:

```
SELECT T.id, T.name, IFNULL(sub.cnt,0)
FROM T
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT parent, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM T
GROUP BY parent) sub
ON T.id = sub.parent
```